# How do I make a file inaccessible with Apache?

Tags: json, apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller

all!

First of all, a list of what software & frameworks I use:
    - XAMPP
    - Apache 2.4
    - Modal-view-controller (mvc) framework with Bootstrap/Twig/Altorouter/PSR4

I have a folder on my site, with a .json file which contains my database login information. Of course, I don't want anybody to have access to this file. At the moment when I go to "127.0.0.1/protected/settings.json" with a browser, it will show me the file (which is a huge security flaw obviously). I thought that I would have to change my .htaccess file to exclude the settings.json file. But I can't seem to find out how.

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance!
Mats de Waard.

Comment: You must keep `protected/settings.json` outside your `DocumentRoot` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to edit your htaccess file in the specified directory where settings.json is.

```
 <Files ~ "\.json">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

This would prevent any json file to be opened. make it as

```
<Files ~ "\settings.json">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

This should work. Works for me though!